# Creating an Azure Active Directory B2C Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've been trying to create an Azure Active Directory B2C Tenant as described in the following Microsoft Article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started

This article uses the old azure portal, though, and when I tried to create a B2C tenant in the new one, it simply created an Active Directory, with no option to make it B2C.  I tried doing it through the old portal and the option to custom create a Directory, like in the tutorial, was no longer there.

I'm wondering if it is still possible to create a B2C tenant, or has Microsoft depreciated this option.  If it is still possible, am I missing something?  What do I need to do now to create one?

Comment: I tried it just now and I was able to create a B2C directory using old Azure Portal. The option to designate a tenant as B2C is disabled when I select a country where this feature is not available (e.g. India). What country did you select?

Comment: I tried a different country and now it worked, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this answer, creation of an Azure AD B2C tenant is only possible through old Azure Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com). Also, there are certain countries/regions where you can't create a B2C tenants.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tenant-type):

> B2C tenants are currently unavailable in the following countries or
>   regions: Afghanistan, Argentina, Australia, Brazil, Chile, Colombia,
>   Ecuador, Hong Kong SAR, India, Indonesia, Iraq, Japan, Korea,
>   Malaysia, New Zealand, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Singapore, Sri
>   Lanka, Taiwan, Thailand, Uruguay and Venezuela. We plan to include
>   them in the future.

If you select one of these countries from the country dropdown, the checkbox for `This is a B2C directory` will be disabled. As of now, you would need to select a country where creation of B2C tenants is allowed.